# Jackson @JsonIgnore an inherited Java 8 default method

Tags: json, java-8, jackson, default-method

I have an interface with a default method:

```
public interface Book {

    String getTitle();

    default String getSentenceForTitle() {
        return "This book's title is " + getTitle();
    }

}
```

... and I have an JPA `@Entity` implementing this interface:

```
@Entity
public class JpaBook implements Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    // ...

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Using this entity, I noticed that Jackson will also serialize the default method `getSentenceForTitle()` - though in my particular case, I don't want `sentenceForTitle` to be serialized.

Is there a way of letting Jackson know that I don't want to have a default methods serialized, yet keep that method's behavior? The current workaround I came up with is overriding the default method, annotating it with `@JsonIgnore`, and delegating to the default method:

```
@Entity
public class JpaBook implements Book {

    // ...

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSentenceForTitle() {
        return Book.super.getSentenceForTitle();
    }

}
```

But this solution can get quite verbose and error-prone for interfaces with many default methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have specific methods/fields ignored this has to be specified somehow and annotation is the simplest way to do that. I can recommend the following options that are simpler than what you have tried:

1. Annotate the default method without overriding it in `JpaBook`. So in `Book`:

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   default String getSentenceForTitle() {
       return "This book's title is " + getTitle();
   }
   ```
2. If `Book` isn't under your control or if there is a list of fields you want to conveniently specify, you can leave `Book` as it is and annotate `JpaBook` with a field or an array of fields to ignore. E.g:

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties("sentenceForTitle")
   class JpaBook implements Book {
   ```

   Or

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties({"sentenceForTitle", "alsoIgnoreThisField"})
   class JpaBook implements Book {
   ```
3. You can also annotate `JpaBook` to serialize all fields (of `JpaBook`) and ignore all getters. You don't need to do anything at `Book` E.g.:

   ```
   @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = ANY, getterVisibility = NONE)
   class JpaBook implements Book {
   ```

Comment: Awesome, I went with the option *`@JsonIgnoreProperties(..)` on the JPA entity class level*. I find it to be the cleanest solution, as it keeps this serialization aspect cohesive to the serialization-centric class.